# In tableau, how to calculate login hours between two dates date wise?

Tags: datetime, logic, formula, tableau-api

For example, my login hour is `7am` to `11pm`. You want to calculate the processing hours between `18/10/2019 5:30:40` and `21/10/2019 14:05:15` date wise. Consider all the holidays and weekends in the final result.

Output we should get for the above example:

```
18/10/2019 16 hrs
19/10/2019 16 hrs
20/10/2019 16 hrs
21/10/2019 7.0875 hrs
```

Answer (score 1):

login hours from 7 AM to 11 PM means 16 hour workday:

```
IF Datediff('day',[LogInTime],[LogOffTime])=0 Then  
(IF Datepart('hour',[LogOffTime])>23 then 23 else Datepart('hour',[LogOffTime]) end)-  
(IF Datepart('hour',[LogInTime])<7 then 7 else Datepart('hour',[LogInTime]) end)  
Else  
Datediff('day',[LogInTime],[LogOffTime])*16 +  
(IF Datepart('hour',[LogOffTime])>23 then 23 else Datepart('hour',[LogOffTime]) end)-  
(IF Datepart('hour',[LogInTime])<7 then 7 else Datepart('hour',[LogInTime]) end)  
End
```